# How to read the results of Dunn's test?

Tags: r, distributions, kruskal-wallis-test, dunn-test

How do I read the results from [Dunn's](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dunn.test/dunn.test.pdf) [test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/dunn-test/info)? Specifically, what do the values in the table below tell me?

I have non-parametric data in 4 groups, and I first did a Kruskal-Wallis test to confirm that the groups' distributions were dissimilar from one another and the aggregate dataset. I then used Dunn's test to see which groups were dissimilar from one another, and which were not.

```
library(dunn.test)
dunn.test(data, g=area, kw=TRUE)
Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data: x and area
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 1730.4401, df = 3, p-value = 0


                        Comparison of x by area                            
                            (No adjustment)                                
Row Mean-|
Col Mean |          A          B          C
---------+---------------------------------
       B |   20.62310
         |     0.0000
         |
       C |   26.66519  -0.087499
         |     0.0000     0.4651
         |
       D |   39.09084   7.401256   9.469204
         |     0.0000     0.0000     0.0000
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The output following the Kruskal-Wallis test provides all possible pairwise comparisons (six in the case of four groups). So the one on the first row compares group B with group A, the first on the second row compares group C with group A, etc.).

The upper number for each comparison is Dunn's pairwise *z* test statistic. The lower number is in this example the raw *p*-value associated with the test (i.e. you would compare to $\alpha/2$, although this *p*-value changes depending on the family-wise error rate or false discovery rate multiple comparisons adjustment option. For stepwise multiple comparison adjustments (e.g. Holm, Benjamini-Hochberg, etc.), the adjusted *p*-values will have an asterisk next to them if your would reject the null hypotheses at the specified significance level (which is not necessarily directly indicated by the adjusted *p*-values since rejection depends on ordering... see the documentation and citations therein for more details.).

I am the author of this package (emailing me, as explicitly indicated in the documentation, would likely be the best way to get in touch with me directly).

Comment: Sorry if this is taking the question in a different direction, but when would you adjust the test? What criteria are necessary in your data for you to want to choose an adjustment?

Comment: @pocketlizard See [family-wise error rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Familywise_error_rate) and [false discovery rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate).

Comment: I have seen that the Kruskal-Wallis values obtained with `kruskal.test` slightly differ from the ones obtained with the option `kw=TRUE` in the above package. Is this due to some approximations or are they two different things?

Comment: @GennaroTedesco `kruskal.test` does not adjust for ties, while `dunn.test` does adjust for ties. As it says in the documentation... just above where it give the email to contact for support questions.